# ASP.NET Textbox not posting back after adding a client side change event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Textbox on my Web Form and I'm using the following code to make it into a jQuery DatePicker:

```
$('#<%= txtServiceDateRequested.ClientID %>').datepicker();
```

That part is working fine. I am also setting the `AutoPostBack` property to `True`, so that whenever a date is selected, the page will post back. This also works fine. The problem I am running into is I am trying to disable my other controls while the page posts back. I am using this code:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#<%= txtServiceDateRequested.ClientID %>').change(function () {
            $('#<%= ddlTimeRequested.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#<%= ddlServiceType.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#<%= ddlService.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#<%= ddlGenderRequested.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#<%= txtServiceDateRequested.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);
        });
    });
```

So I am binding to the `change` event of my textbox (datepicker). When I add this code, it does, indeed, disable my controls like it should and it appears to do a postback, but when I put a break point on my C# code behind:

```
protected void txtServiceDateRequested_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FixItems(); // I'm putting a breakpoint here
}
```

For some reason, the breakpoint is never hit. If I comment out that javascript code above that binds the `change` event and disables the controls, then the breakpoint hits as expected. Can someone tell me why my breakpoint doesn't hit when I uncomment and enable the JS code above?

EDIT:

After doing some playing around, the issue seems to be when the textbox itself gets disabled. From what I am speculating, I am clicking on the textbox, my jquery calendar shows up. Then I'm selecting a date. Then it appears my disable code is getting executed, then jquery is trying to insert the date I selected into the textbox. But since the textbox is disabled, it isn't putting the new date in there. So maybe I need a way to make the jquery calendar code execute first, before my disable code is fired?

Answer (score 1):

You have to just add `AutoPostBack="true"` for the Textbox. I have tested with below code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $(".datepicker").datepicker({
             onSelect: function () {
                 this.fireEvent && this.fireEvent('onchange') || $(this).change();
             }
         });
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker"                   
     OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The change method is overriding the default event `__doPostBack` from ASP.NET, then It will never call the server.

You should use **Bind** instead, to attach another function to the change method:

```
$('#<%= txtServiceDateRequested.ClientID %>').bind( "change", function( event ) {
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: I changed it to `bind`, but it still doesn't seem to hit my breakpoint. I also tried `on`. Still no luck.

Comment: Just curious, where this js block? you should put this after the body! I tried this here and works, maybe we missing something else. Try to checkout wich evets are binded to you element and check out for any JS error in Firebug or Chrome Console

Comment: Its using a Master page. I have the script tag just before the closing `</asp:Content>` tag. Inside the Master page, the `<asp:Content>` tag is in between the `<form>` tag. So it would render similar to this: `<html><body><form> My HTML Code...My JS Code</form></body></html>`

Comment: I'm using Chrome and I'm looking at the console and not seeing any javascript errors. Console screen is blank.

Comment: Fals -- If it'll help, I can post my entire code to the file, if you want. Its not that big.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling controls when change event fires, add it to either [onClose](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) or [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect).
So your code might look like

```
    $("#<%= txtServiceDateRequested.ClientID %>").datepicker({
       onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                     $('#<%= ddlTimeRequested.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
                     $('#<%= ddlServiceType.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
                     $('#<%= ddlService.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
                     $('#<%= ddlGenderRequested.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
                     $('#<%= txtServiceDateRequested.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```